# Problem with Gummi: Compilation Program is Missing

Tags: editors

I have recently upgraded my system from TexLive2010 to TexLive2012.

I have correctly set my Environment Variables and everything works well from the Command Line. My OS is OpenSuse 11.4.

My Problem is:

- If I invoke the LaTex Editor Gummi from Terminal, everything works fine.
- But if I invoke it through Righ-Clicking a File (Open with Gummi) or by right-clicking on Gummi icon, I get: "Compilation Program is Missing".

I have already made sure that rubber, xetex & latexmk are installed (as suggested by the below mentioned link):

http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi/wiki/Troubleshooting#compilation-program-is-missing

Can anybody give me some pointers to resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I just install/reinstall texlive and it works: # yum reinstall texlive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website [troubleshooting](http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi/wiki/Troubleshooting#compilation-program-is-missing) says on section "Gummi won’t start or load correctly after an upgrade.":

> Gummi won’t start or load correctly after an upgrade.¶
>
> Try to remove the files snippets.cfg and gummi.cfg that are located at
>   /home/[*{your-username}*]/.config/gummi. Removing them will have Gummi
>   re-create the default configuration when it is next started, so don’t
>   forget to back them up if you want to retain your configuration.

So when you have installed TeXLive new delete both old `snippets.cfg` and `gummi.cfg` to get new on for using with TeXLive 2012. Because `gummi`is under development install the actual version (today: Gummi 0.6.4 (June 24th, 2012)).

If Gummi still can't found the compilation program you can try to copy pdflatex executable to `/usr/local/bin` and run it again. (If you have still problems a reboot could help.)

Answer (score 6):

For some reason Gummi doesn't seem to search PATH and adding the texlive directory to it doesn't work, so ...

Rather than copying the binaries across as the accepted answer suggests, just create symlinks to *all* the binaries in your texlive directory, substituting 2012 with whatever your version of TeX Live is:

- 32 bit:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux/* /usr/local/bin/
  ```
- 64 bit:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/* /usr/local/bin/
  ```

You need to create links to all the binaries (i.e. not just pdflatex), as otherwise some documents would fail to compile.